# Unable to delete a folder made on a remote share (created using PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, security, permissions, filesystems, san

Afternoon guys, been a while;

I've run into an interesting issue, I created a powershell script that would create a folder with some sub folders on a network share we have, all that works perfectly fine.

The twist comes when I try to delete that folder; I select it and hit delete, and it deletes everything but the last folder saying there are permission issue and that I don't have permissions to delete the folder. I check the security properties and I can't see anything (when you can see everyone that has access before you delete it). The only way I'm able to actually delete the folder(s) is through logging into our SAN and deleting it from the menu.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on. Why everything seems fine when everything is created, but then go an delete it and it says 'No thank you'

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reason, but it is likely an error of permission, check the permissions on the network share, the user must have at least `modify` or `full control` you can also simply run `powershell` as `administrator`, also you can check if it come from inheritance, when you create a folder it get its permission from the parent folder by default, check those.

If nothing work go check the logs of your server